# How to know if a Xul window is minimized?

Tags: xul

Xul's `window.sizemode` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/sizemode) says:

> When a window is minimized, the
>   sizemode attribute is not updated.
>   This is done so that if a window is
>   closed while minimized, its persisted
>   sizemode attribute wouldn't be
>   minimized.

so, is there a way to know when it's minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you pointed said:

> To get the window state from
>   JavaScript code, use
>   window.windowState.

The *window.windowState* link is broken. But I could find its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMChromeWindow#Attributes). It says you can check if the attribute **windowState** is equals to the constant **STATE_MINIMIZED**.